# Alternative to c# User-Defined Conversions in Java

Tags: c#, java

Is there something like [User-Defined conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288476%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in Java or any suggestion on how can I acchive same effect in java without adding tens of `.toXXXX` methods

I haven't used c# for a while so I can't remember right name for it but I also remember that in c# I was able to pass first parameter to function without using notation

```
Foo(MyClass instance)
```

but rather

```
instance.Foo()
```

If I remember correctly I had to use this keyword before MyClass something like `Foo(this MyClass instance)` but as I said I haven't used c# for a while so I cant remember

Can anyone tell me what are the alternatives to this two "methods" in Java

Comment: Java does not have [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's nothing like user-defined conversions in Java. Personally I dislike using *implicit* user-defined conversions in C# anyway, and rarely even write explicit ones. If the lack of them is causing you to add *tens* of `toXXX` methods then you should probably rethink just how widely you'd use conversions in C#.

The second feature you're talking about is [*extension methods*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) which also aren't present in Java. You just have to call static methods as normal.